# Does dart support compile to binary code?

Tags: dart

I want to use Dart as business project which will deploy on a customer's server.

At present I just know upload the whole source code to the server, there is no privacy...

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Dart server code. Client code is transpiled to JavaScript, tree-shaken, and minified. This is quite some obfuscation.

For server side code you can use snapshots.

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/snapshots/. Snapshots still contain the readable source but everything packed into one file.
See also [What is the difference between Dart's snapshots and Java bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547163/what-is-the-difference-between-darts-snapshots-and-java-bytecode)

There is ongoing work to create precompiled snapshots.
Normally Dart code is compiled at runtime before a function is executed the first time. For precompiled snapshots Dart source is compiled ahead of time.

Running

```
dart --gen-precompiled-snapshot
```

prints

> Precompiled snapshots must be generated with dart_bootstrap.
>   Usage: dart []  []

I haven't found a `dart_bootstrap` command in the SDK.

I guess we will have to wait a bit more until this feature will be made available.